# viewport-fit=cover and padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top) not working with Plaid widget on iphone 12 simulator

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, plaid

I'm trying to make the Plaid widget on my iOS device move down because the top is currently being going into the notches. I've tried:
`viewport-fit=cover & padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top), @supports (padding: max(0px)) {} suggested by apple, and padding-top: min(120px, env(safe-area-inset-top)).` Nothing has worked or even moved the Plaid widget. I'm wondering if the problem has to do with the widget itself and not my app. Any help is appreciated!